# Maven Build Successful on Jenkins, but fails at runtime

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins

I have a Spring application that runs fine when I build as jenkins user (sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins). But when I use my freestyle job on Jenkins, it fails at runtime citing a bean not found error.

Error Log - Bean not found:

[image: Error Log - Bean not found]

Comment: You mean you _built_ it with Jenkins or you _ran_ it with Jenkins?

Comment: I built it with Jenkins. The image above is the log at runtime.

Comment: A successful build does not mean that the artifact runs without runtime problems. Maybe a jar is missing that is needed at runtime but not at compile time.